# [rospack] Error: package 'image_view' not found

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I use ubuntu14.04 on Raspberry Pi 2
I installed ros-indigo-desktop

I ran the following command

```
$ roscore 
$ rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw
```

rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw caused an error

```
[rospack] Error: package 'image_view' not found
```

Please give me some advice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217806/%5Brospack%5D-error:-package-%27image_view%27-not-found/) by [Kazuki Kadonaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/23157/kazuki-kadonaka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-09-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have `image_view` installed?

Try `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-image-view`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kazuki Kadonaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/23157/kazuki-kadonaka/) on 2015-09-17**:
I didn't have it
Thanks